# How Bad Is Bullying in Judaism?

Tags: morality

Say there is another Jew who is being a bully, a mean person or just plain spiteful and angrily argumentative...

I read that harmful or useless speech is a more serious sin than murder yet we all do it at some point.

I have heard anger compared to idolatry as well, if someone is intentionally and with anger or malice speaking to or about a fellow Jew is that like murdering and worshipping idols?

Likewise if a person who claims to be Jewish harassed or has taken joy in belittling or hurting the feelings of another human being, how then should we deal with such a person?

Sometimes we can't avoid people like this, they show up everywhere and there is always one in every crowd.

How then does one handle the situation appropriately and decently when faced with such people?

How can we help people who act this way to grow past their anger and stop hurting others when all they do, sometimes everything that they do or say makes people seriously upset or angry?

How do we ourselves avoid falling into the trap of sinking to the levels of doing such things like this ourselves when faced with a mean, angry, spiteful, lying or back stabbing individual?

When someone hurts us and we want to take the eye for an eye what do we need to know as Jews to be a bigger person so that instead of yelling at someone for yelling we can make better choices about how to handle these things?

Comment: הֱוֵי מִתְפַּלֵּל בִּשְׁלוֹמָהּ שֶׁל מַלְכוּת , שֶׁאִלְמָלֵא מוֹרָאָהּ, אִישׁ  אֶת רֵעֵהוּ חַיִּים בָּלָעוּ.

Comment: I think this question would be a great deal more answerable if you'd [edit] it to be sharper. "How bad is it," by itself, is pretty much impossible to answer definitively, since readers don't know on what scale of "badness" to judge. The following yes/no question about whether it's equivalent to idolatry and anger is much sharper; that part could be improved if you'd add in more about what you mean by "Idolatry Bad like being angry is," preferably by describing your source for that concept.

Comment: @user  I'm on a "Smart" phone could you please post a translation I can't read Hebrew fluently enough when the letters are normal sized and that is teeny tiny on my phone. Unless AA would care to provide it.

Comment: Rebecca, you are correct. I can't find the source for it at hand but there are some Jews that believe Loshan Hora (gossip, libel, slander, etc.) is worse than murder as it harms the target as well as all those who listen. I a reasonably sure it originates from Chofetz Chaim. As far as degree of 'badness', scripture discusses measure for measure and eye for an an eye--which is not interpreted by all Jews as revenge but as just (as in justice/fairness) punishment relative to the crime or tort. This suggests degree of 'badness' may be actually exist.

Comment: Rebbeca one of the ten martyrs told us to pray for the welfare of the government because without fear of the government people would swallow each other alive. My point was you don't have to agree with the guy in charge who I know this is focused at, but appreciate that without people like him this site would be much worse. Just think how bad every comment section of a site without mods is. Ever read the comments under every video on YouTube? All the racist homophobic rembarks, calling each other Hitler? Every single one! That's what would happen here.

Comment: I am newly religious in the last few years and I was listening to a lecture by Rabbi Doctor Lord Jonathan Sacks whom I listen to almost more than any other speaker since we've replaced television with meaningful lectures in our home. The lecture was on the power of words. This is when I first heard Loshan Hara compared to Murder. Rabbi Mizrachi another favorite taught me that it's not a literal eye, but fair compensation in equal measure relative to the offence.

Comment: If the goal of this post is to advance a point rather than to ask for information, as the language "isn't that ..." and some of these comments seem to indicate, then it won't work well as a productive question post. I encourage you to take a look at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for some general points on what types of posts don't work well as question posts.

Comment: I seriously want to know how to take people who act like that. How do we react to people like that? How do you help someone who is behaving like that?

Comment: @RebeccaBurns The question post, as it stands, is about characterizing how bad bullying is, not about practical methods for reacting to it or helping its perpetrators. If those are actually what you want to know, then I'd suggest [edit]ing this post to be asking for what practical advice Jewish sources provide for reacting to bullying. In any case, the current text reads more like it's trying to make a point than like it's seeking information, so I'd recommend editing it to be clearly the latter.

Comment: @ Isaac - You're totally right. Thank you for your advice and honesty.

Comment: So, to confirm, there's three different questions: how to respond to a bully in the moment, how to respond to a bully when s/he's not bullying, and how to keep yourself from becoming a bully.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think the question is too broad at this point.

Comment: @DonielF Also, how bad bullying is and if it's like AZ

Comment: @DoubleAA You're right, it is pretty broad. I vote to split off the advice questions.

Comment: @RebeccaBurns can you pare this down to one clear question that's clearly about Judaism? I understand that it can be frustrating to go through many edit cycles, but what we're all trying to do is to work together to make sure that we end up with a clear, answerable question that will then attract clear, useful answers, all of which will be maintained permanently on Mi Yodeya as a resource for others on the Internet who are interested in similar issues. [This tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) might be useful in describing the Q&A rubric Mi Yodeya is built on.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Do you approve of my closing this as too broad?

Comment: @DoubleAA there are multiple close reasons that apply, in my opinion. In my opinion, each of the sub-questions would need significant work to be something we can productively deal with, or I'd just edit down to one of them myself.